# Derive end date by shifting unique values using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, lag

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'subjectID' :[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2],'start_date': 
  ['10/30/2006 08:04','10/30/2006 08:04','11/30/2006 11:01','12/30/2006 02:04','02/13/2007 07:24','04/20/2007 08:34',
   '02/20/2007 06:44','01/20/2007 03:44','11/09/2006 02:03']})
```

What I would like to do is

1) sort the dataframe by two columns (subject_id and start_date for each subject). **Meaning for each subject the start date has to be arranged in ascending order. Like group by subject_id and sort their start_date values**

2) Fill the **end_date column for each patient by fetching the next unique value of start_date for the same patient.**

3) As we follow step 2, we will encounter that last record of each subject will have no other values look beyond, so **we just add 10 days to get the end date for last record for each subject**

This is what I tried

```
df = df.sort_values(['subjectID', 'start_date'], ascending=[True,True]) # works but is this same as group by and sort after?
df['end_date'] = df.groupby('subjectID')['start_date'].unique().shift(-1) # this doesn't work
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#converting to datetimes
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])

#sorting
df = df.sort_values(['subjectID', 'start_date'])
#created timestamp for each last value of group and added 10 days
s = df.drop_duplicates('subjectID', keep='last')['start_date'] + pd.Timedelta(10, unit='d')

#shifting without duplicates, added missing values by reindex and forward filling 
df['end_date'] = (df.drop_duplicates(['subjectID','start_date'])
                   .groupby('subjectID')['start_date']
                   .shift(-1)
                   .reindex(df.index)
                   .groupby(df['subjectID'])
                   .ffill()
                   )
#last set last values of groups
df['end_date'].update(s)
print (df)
  subjectID          start_date            end_date
0          1 2006-10-30 08:04:00 2006-11-30 11:01:00
1          1 2006-10-30 08:04:00 2006-11-30 11:01:00
2          1 2006-11-30 11:01:00 2006-12-30 02:04:00
3          1 2006-12-30 02:04:00 2007-02-13 07:24:00
4          1 2007-02-13 07:24:00 2007-04-20 08:34:00
5          1 2007-04-20 08:34:00 2007-04-30 08:34:00
8          2 2006-11-09 02:03:00 2007-01-20 03:44:00
7          2 2007-01-20 03:44:00 2007-02-20 06:44:00
6          2 2007-02-20 06:44:00 2007-03-02 06:44:00
```

Comment: @TheGreat - `df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])` is necessary, added to solution

Comment: I guess when it adds 10 days, it checks whether day 30/31 is actually present in the month and not just add 10 values. Am I right?

Comment: @TheGreat - yes, you are right. 2007-02-30 should be invalid datetime

Comment: @TheGreat - In another words it add 10 days by calendar ;)